Wave equation with spatially dependent parameters
Not sure if this is the best site for this question, but I think some folks here may have a good answer. My question is simply: How should the wave equation with spatially dependent wave speed look like? I've seen both
$$
\partial_{tt} u(t,x) = c(x)^2\Delta u(t,x)
$$
and
$$
\partial_{tt} u(t,x) = \nabla\cdot(c(x)^2\nabla u(t,x)).
$$
Which one is used for which physical models? I think that the wave speed $c$ is used is just because it turn out that the (constant) coefficient in front of the $\Delta$ turn out the be the square of the speed of the wave. In a physical model, other quantities like mass and material properties are used and I would love to get some insight into which quantity should appear where. A variable mass $m(x)$ should appear in front of the Laplace or inside? I found this pretty hard to google and would hope to get some background and pointers on that topic.

Note that your equations are dimensionally wrong, [1/t] on LHS and [1/t^2] on RHS

It needs to be second time derivatives in both equations to be the wave equation.

Regardless, I believe that both forms appear in models, depending on modeling assumptions. But in the second case, it would typically be $\rho(x)\partial_t^2 u(x,t) = \nabla \cdot a(x) \nabla u(x,t)$ where $\rho$ appears because then you have mass times acceleration on the left -- i.e., this is Newton's law.

Thanks, corected!

@WolfgangBangerth Oh, that would mean that one would have $\partial_{tt} u(x,t)= \rho(x)^{-1}\nabla(\cdot a(x)\nabla u(x,t))$, so a term inside and another outside.

@WolfgangBangerth, I think that you answered the question. Would you mind expanding it into an answer?

@nicoguaro I've got nothing to add to the three lines above. I don't think that's worthy of an actual answer :-)
